# Process IQueryable with a new Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I've been working with improving a library that is built using EF 5.  I would like to use the Parallel library to speed performance up.  I understand that a DbContext is not thread safe and that for every transaction a new DbContext would need to be created.

The problem I believe I am having is how to get a new context generated every time my IQueryable is iterated over.  Here is a truncated method of my implementation:

```
    public virtual void ProcessAttachments(IQueryable<File> results)
    {            
        var uniqueOrderKeys = results.Select(r => r.ForeignKey).Distinct();
        //process each order
        Parallel.ForEach(uniqueOrderKeys, key =>
        {                                                                                                                                                         
            var key1 = key;
            var resultsForKey = results.Where(result => result.ForeignKey == key1);

            //process File objects for the order
            Parallel.ForEach(resultsForKey, result =>
            {                                                                                              
                string orderNum;
                using (var da = new DataAccess()) //DataAccess creates the DbContext and is implementing IDisposable
                {
                    orderNum = da.GetOrderNumberByOrderKey(key);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to specify a new DbContext to be used as my IQueryable results are looped through and retrieved?

Comment: I wonder how much benefit you get from making your queries parallel as opposed to have just one query that gets you the data you need. What you have seems to be sending a lot of queries to the database and it appears to me it should be possible to get everything in just one query.

Comment: processing in parallel like I have in my example takes about 2 minutes for a given data set.  The same data set took about 6 minutes to process before.  The difference was very noticeable.  Am I creating an extra few hundred connections to the database?  Maybe.  Does it really matter?  I don't think so.

Comment: Do you know what took the most time? 6 minutes seems very long... You don't seem to care about tracking - have you tried getting the entities using `.AsNoTracking()`? How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: i'll have to look up what .AsNoTracking() does.  The bulk of the 6 minutes was the time it took to retrieve the data.  I did a .ToList() on my IQueryable<File> results to force all the data to be pulled at once, that took about 6 minutes.  The data we're talking about is about 1000 .jpg blobs.  The rest of the code converts the File object back to a .jpg and renames it as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I just put this together and I think it may help you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WhereverYourObjectContextLives;


/// <summary>
/// Provides an iterator pattern over a collection such that the results may be processed in parallel.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ParallelSkipTakeIterator <T>
{
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private int batchSize;

    private Expression<Func<T, int>> orderBy;

    private ParallelQuery<T> currentBatch;


    /// <summary>
    /// Build the iterator, specifying an Order By function, and optionally a <code>batchSize</code>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orderBy">Function which selects the id to sort by</param>
    /// <param name="batchSize">number of rows to return at once - defaults to 1000</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <code>batchSize</code> balances overhead with cost of parallelizing and instantiating
    /// new database contexts.  This should be scaled based on observed performance.
    /// </remarks>
    public ParallelSkipTakeIterator(Expression<Func<T, int>> orderBy, int batchSize = 1000)
    {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.orderBy = orderBy;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Accesses the materialized result of the most recent iteration (execution of the query).
    /// </summary>
    public ParallelQuery<T> CurrentBatch
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.currentBatch == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must call HasNext at least once before accessing the CurrentBatch.");
            }
            return this.currentBatch;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does the current iterator have another batch of data to process?
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if more data can be accessed via <code>CurrentBatch</code></returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Creates a new database context, issues a query, and places a materialized collection in <code>CurrentBatch</code>.
    /// Context is disposed once the query is issued.
    /// Materialized collection is specified by <code>BuildIQueryable</code>.  Use of any associated navigation properties
    /// must be accounted for by using the appropriate <code>.Include</code> operator where the query is
    /// built in <code>BuildIQueryable</code>.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool HasNext()
    {
        using (YourObjectContextHere db = new YourObjectContextHere())
        {

            this.currentBatch = this.BuildIQueryable(db)
                .OrderBy(this.orderBy)
                .Skip(this.currentIndex)
                .Take(this.batchSize)
                .ToList()
                .AsParallel();

            this.currentIndex += this.batchSize;
            return currentBatch.Count() > 0;
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given a Database Context, builds a query which can be executed in batches.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="db">context on which to build and execute the query</param>
    /// <returns>a query which will be executed and materialized</returns>
    /// <remarks>Context will be disposed as soon a HasNext has been executed.</remarks>
    protected abstract IQueryable<T> BuildIQueryable(YourObjectContextHere db);
}
```

You may then subclass this thing and implement `BuildIQueryable` as follows:

```
    class MyObjectIterator: ParallelSkipTakeIterator<MyObject>
    {
        private List<int> instanceIds;

        public PropertyRecordMatchFileIterator(List<int> someExtraInfoNeededByQuery)
            : base(f => f.InstanceId)
        {
            this.instanceIds = someExtraInfoNeededByQuery;
        }

        protected override IQueryable<MyObject> BuildIQueryable(YourObjectContextHere db)
        {
            IQueryable<MyObject> myObjects= db.SomeCollection.Select(x => this.instanceIds.Contains(x).Include("SomethingImportant");

            return myObjects;
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can loop over the data sets as so:

```
        MyObjectIterator myIterator = new MyObjectIterator(someExtraInfoNeededByQuery);
        while (myIterator.HasNext())
        {
            ParallelQuery<MyObject> query = myIterator.CurrentBatch;
            query.ForAll(item =>
                doSomethingCool(item));
        }
```